# Translation of a string in code behind in a localresource file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, localization

I created local resource files with VisualStudio (.resx and .fr.resx) for each page. 
All the text of controls in the .aspx page can be translated now.

But can I also translate strings in my code behind in this loacal resource file?
If yes, how can I read the value in code behind out of my local .resx files in my App_LocalResources map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try...

Simply call the GetLocalResourceObject method on your current page:

```
GetLocalResourceObject("yourkey").ToString();

GetGlobalResourceObject("MyGlobalResources", "HelloWorldString").ToString();
```

Comment: For "global" access: HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject