# resources files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a folder in asp.net 4.0 application with local resource files for different cultures. These resource files have name/value pairs. I want to use these name/value pairs in asp.net page.

These resource files are located in another project but in same solution. There are 15 resource files for 15 different cultures. I want to access them in different web project in same solution. do I need to use global resources syntax or what because local resource method is returning null

Comment: Check this, if that can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855599/translation-of-a-string-in-code-behind-in-a-localresource-file/5855635#5855635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local and global resources work in a Web application scope.

If you want to share same resource files across Web application you'll find better implementing a ResourceManager-derived class which may retrieve such resources from some common location.

Another solution would be placing your resources in a database in order to share them across multiple applications by implementing a custom ResourceManager too. CodeProject has an article talking about how to achieve this:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Custom_Resource_Reader.aspx

Finally, I'd suggest a MSBuild approach so when you update your resources, some MSBuild script would spread changes in all Web applications, placing your up-to-date resource files everywhere. You maintain resources in a single place, but MSBuild does the job of copying files for you. Copy files in MSBuild is very easy because it has an "xcopy" command.

This last approach has a good point: you can use built-in, out-of-the-box ASP.NET ResourceManager implementation.

Everything has its pros and cons.